# Editing permissions of MediaWiki default namespaces

Tags: permissions, mediawiki

At the moment I'm trying to set some custom premissions for the "user:" Namespace, because normal users shouldn't be allowed to edit or create an article but setting up their personal article. Therefore they need the rights "edit" and "createpage", which i disabled for them.
I've tried the default ID "2", you find it here: [**Link**](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension_namespace_registration) and setting up an own namespace, in my case it was "102". But both versions didn't worked, or was something wrong with my code?

```
$wgGroupPermissions['user'] ['ns102_edit'] = true;
$wgGroupPermissions['user'] ['ns102_create'] = true;
```

And

```
$wgGroupPermissions['user'] ['ns2_edit'] = true;
$wgGroupPermissions['user'] ['ns2_create'] = true;
```

Comment: Please paste all the code you are using, these lines give users the right `ns2_edit`, but how do you tell the wiki what `ns2_edit` means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to restrict editing in a namespace, you should use [`$wgNamespaceProtection`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3a%24wgNamespaceProtection), e.g. like this:

```
$wgNamespaceProtection[NS_MAIN]     = $wgNamespaceProtection[NS_MEDIAWIKI]  =
$wgNamespaceProtection[NS_PROJECT]  = $wgNamespaceProtection[NS_FILE] =
$wgNamespaceProtection[NS_TEMPLATE] = $wgNamespaceProtection[NS_HELP]  =
$wgNamespaceProtection[NS_CATEGORY] = array( 'sysop' );
```

This will make the mentioned namespaces read only to anyone but the site admins. Talk pages are still editable. You might want to have a look at the extension [Lockdown](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aLockdown) as well. It make per namespace priviligies easier to maintain.

In your case it sound to me like you also want to use [UserPageEditProtection](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aUserPageEditProtection), to prevent users to edit each other user pages.

Comment: Thanks for the both links. Didn't thought about the last plugin. Problem is fixed now :)